# complex(ish) pivot_longer in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset that roughly looks like this:

```
person_id mem_was_there_1 mem_was_there_2 mem_was_there_3 new_number_yn_1 new_number_yn_2 new_number_yn_3
      <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl> <lgl>           <lgl>           <lgl>          
1       100               1               2               3 FALSE           TRUE            FALSE          
2       101               4               5               6 TRUE            FALSE           FALSE
```

I need to pivot this data into something like this:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  person_id    nr mem_was_there new_number_yn
      <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl> <lgl>        
1       100     1             1 FALSE        
2       100     2             2 TRUE         
3       100     3             3 FALSE        
4       101     1             4 TRUE         
5       101     2             5 FALSE        
6       101     3             6 FALSE
```

I would like to use a `pivot_longer()` from `dplyr` option. I tried using this code, but I do not use what to fill in at the ??? to regex to the third `_`. Ideally, I would like a separate `names_sep` for both  'mem_was_there_xx' and 'new_number_yn_xx'

```
df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(matches("^mem_was_there"), matches("^new_number_yn")), 
               names_to = c('.value', 'nr'), 
               names_sep = ??? )
```

```
df1 <-
 tribble(~person_id, ~mem_was_there_1, ~mem_was_there_2, ~mem_was_there_3, ~new_number_yn_1,  ~new_number_yn_2, ~new_number_yn_3,
         100, 1, 2, 3, F, T, F,
         101, 4, 5, 6, T, F, F)
```

Comment: I would recommend to create a pivot_longer_spec object, which essentially is a data frame where you map your old variable names to your new desired variable names. Pretty awesome and flexible that way.

Comment: See an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61367970/2725773

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As deschen recommended, I played around with the regex a bit and this pivot longer call does work as expected. (and is a bit cleaner than having to manually create the `pivot_longer_spec` and also works if there are an unequal amount of mem_was_there_x and new_number_yn_y (it will just insert missings, where applicable)

```
df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(matches("^mem_was_there"), matches("^new_number_yn")),
    names_to = c('.value', 'nr'),
    names_pattern = "([A-Za-z_]+_)([0-9]*)")
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
spec <- data.frame(.name  = names(df1)[-1],
                   nr     = rep(1:3, 2),
                   .value = c(rep("mem_was_there", 3), rep("new_number_yn", 3)),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(tidyverse)    
df1 %>%
  pivot_longer_spec(., spec)
```

gives:

```
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#   person_id    nr mem_was_there new_number_yn
#       <dbl> <int>         <dbl> <lgl>        
# 1       100     1             1 FALSE        
# 2       100     2             2 TRUE         
# 3       100     3             3 FALSE        
# 4       101     1             4 TRUE         
# 5       101     2             5 FALSE        
# 6       101     3             6 FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks, this indeed works for this small fake dataset, but does not scale very well to larger datasets, where for example the nr is unknown (my data it is between 300 and 500 ) and when there are many different variables you want to exclude from the pivot or when the exact order of variables are not know either. Will keep this open for now, hoping on a pivot_longer() solution that will allow for a split just before the third `_`. I now jut use two pivot_longer calls and then a left_join().

Comment: There‘s probably a regex way of splitting your names and then use the .value thing. However, I‘m also sure that you can dynamically create the spec data frame. You know the columns and column positions from your original wide format data set, so then it‘s only the question how to smartly put that info into the spec object.